# Getting latest record when using Group by in magento

Tags: mysql

I am facing one issue that I want to get latest records from collection when using group by & sort order but getting the first record from groups (not the latest one). I am grouping the collection by email id so that means I should get one record per email id. Now I am getting that but the real issue is the record which comes is the older one not the latest one. I am ordering the collection with ID but still not luck.

Here is my code :-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('messagebox/messagebox')->getCollection();
$collection->AddFieldToFilter('toemail',$this->escapeHtml($this->helper('messagebox')->getUserEmail()));
$collection->getSelect('*')
    ->columns('MAX(messagebox_id) as max_id')
    ->group(array('fromemail'))
    ->order('max_id desc');
```

First I am getting the collection then doing filter, then grouping it & then ordering it. In this case the records are not coming latest but the older.

I am explaining with the table & output. My table is like this :-

```
messagebox_id  fromemail  toemail     message      created_time
1              an@el.com  kl@el.com   sample msg   2015-09-10 07:26:49
2              an@el.com  kl@el.com   Hi Hello     2015-09-10 07:28:28
3              an@el.com  kl@el.com   Hi Fine?     2015-09-10 07:30:20
4              hk@el.com  kl@el.com   Hi Kl        2015-09-16 07:37:20
5              hk@el.com  kl@el.com   Hi 2nd Msg   2015-09-16 07:38:49
```

Now if we hit the above query, the output will come like this :-

```
messagebox_id  fromemail  toemail     message      created_time
1              an@el.com  kl@el.com   sample msg   2015-09-10 07:26:49
4              hk@el.com  kl@el.com   Hi Kl        2015-09-16 07:37:20
```

The expected output is :-

```
messagebox_id  fromemail  toemail     message      created_time
3              an@el.com  kl@el.com   Hi Fine?     2015-09-10 07:30:20
5              hk@el.com  kl@el.com   Hi 2nd Msg   2015-09-16 07:38:49
```

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: Hi,

I have got the mysql query but now the last & final question is how to write that query in magento way? My Query is :-

select * from messagebox where messagebox_id in (select max(messagebox_id) from messagebox group by fromemail) AND toemail ='kl@el.com'

Can anyone please assist?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I got the solution :)

Here is the code :-

```
/* Loading IDs */
$collection = Mage::getModel('messagebox/messagebox')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->where('toemail = "kl@el.com"')
->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
->columns(array('MAX(messagebox_id) as max_id'))
->group(array('fromemail'));

$productIds = array();
foreach ($collection->getData() as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $v){
        $productIds[] = $v;
    }
}

/* Loading Messages */
$collectionMessage = Mage::getModel('messagebox/messagebox')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('messagebox_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone :)